# Generate binary matrix of all nCm up to certain m with ncol=n

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, combn

Wondering if there's a faster way to achieve the following:

I have a vector of max. length `long1` which is all zeros. 
How do I generate a matrix of all possible combinations of ones in certain positions up to and including the maximum `max1s`.

The following works, but seems to be rather inefficient when the return matrix is large e.g. >1e5.

```
### longest series of zeros
long1 <- 4
### max no. of 1s
max1s <- 2
### get combinations up to long1
f1 <- function(i) t(combinat::combn(seq.int(long1),
                                    m=i, simplify=TRUE))
### list of positions in target matrix to be made 1s
### each list element represents column positions of 1s
l1 <- sapply(1:max1s, f1)
### no. rows in return matrix
nrow1 <- sum(unlist(lapply(l1, nrow)))
### set up matrix of zeros
c2 <- matrix(0L, nrow=nrow1, ncol=long1)
### rows to start at for each 'i' in length(l1) below
nrow2 <- c(1, 1+cumsum(unlist(lapply(l1, nrow))))
for (i in 1:length(l1)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(l1[[i]])){
### now iterate over each row in that element of l1
### set relevant position in matrix to 1
        c2[nrow2[i]+(j-1), l1[[i]][j, ] ] <-  1L
    }}
```

In this case it's all combinations of `1`s, up to a max of 2, in a vector of length 4:

```
> c2
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    1    0
 [7,]    1    0    0    1
 [8,]    0    1    1    0
 [9,]    0    1    0    1
[10,]    0    0    1    1
```

I would prefer to avoid using `combinat::hcube` then eliminating rows with more than a certain no. of `1`s as this approach will create needlessly large matrices for an application like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just separately compute the combinations of each size using `combn` and then use `do.call` with `rbind` to combine them all together:

```
allcombo <- function(long1, max1s) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:max1s, function(num1) {
    t(apply(combn(long1, num1), 2, function(x) {
      col = rep(0, long1)
      col[x] = 1
      col
    }))
  }))
}
```

I've stored your posted solution in function `OP`. We can check they return the same values:

```
all.equal(OP(20, 5), allcombo(20, 5))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now we can benchmark (there are 21699 returned rows):

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(20, 5), allcombo(20, 5))
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#        OP(20, 5) 242.4120 256.5791 269.7237 292.7131 556.5984   100
#  allcombo(20, 5) 150.4291 179.2588 188.4840 200.9898 448.2214   100
```

So this approach using `combn` is a bit faster (30% on my computer for this set of parameters).